# Delegate Method only Firing after 5 or so Button Presses?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, debugging, delegates

I'm having the most bizarre problem which I'm not even close to figuring out. I have a button which fires a delegate method. Once upon a time it was working fine, but after making some changes to my code, now the delegate method only fires after I push the button x amount of times (the changes I made to the code had nothing to do with the infrastructure that connects the delegate together). It varies, it can be 5 times to 10 times. I used the analyzer to check for memory leaks and there aren't any.

There is too much code for me to paste here (I don't even know where to start or where the problem could be), but I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this problem before, or what could be causing it? This is very odd and have no clue what could be causing it.

Comment: clean, delete derived data, quit xcode & restart & check again..

Comment: sounds like some other view is getting the touch events over the button.  I've also seen this type of behavior when the touch area is too small (either because the button is too small or because it's getting clipped by another view)

Comment: I am use iOS 6.0 simulator and have a hang after starting application. Maybe you have same problem?

Comment: @MikeM - I think you're correct, it had to do with the UI as I switched the delegate call to another button and it worked. do you want to put this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like some other view is getting the touch events over the button. I've also seen this type of behavior when the touch area is too small (either because the button is too small or because it's getting clipped by another view)

Comment: It definitely was something with the UI, cause when I switched the delegate call to another button it worked fine. I notice I might have added another very small view on accident that is popping up over my button, I think this caused it.